# Don't show insert tile second insert do in localDataBace

Tags: c#, .net

I want insert some data to `localdatabace` and insert is successfully done but don't show in my `datagridview` tile second insert do for `debog` it I Call Select All end of my insert and see the last insert don't show in it but whene i insert a next data , last data will be showing  can every one help me pleas?

```
public void connect()
{
    String conString = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\\hana\\documents\\visual studio 2017\\Projects\\Bank\\Bank\\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True";

    SqlConnection sql = new SqlConnection(conString);
    String sqll = "Insert into TblBank (txtTodayDate" +
        ",txtSahebanHesab" +
        ",txtShobe" +
        ",txtShomareMoshtari" +
        ",txtShoareHesab" +
        ",cmbNoeHesab" +
        ",txtSarresid" +

        ")";
    try
    {
        sql.Open();

        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(sqll, sql);
        SqlCommand sc = new SqlCommand(sqll,sql);

        sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("todayDate", new PersianDateTime(dtpTodayDate.the_date).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"));
        sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("sahebanHesab", txtSahebHesabName.Text);
        sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("shobe", txtshobe.Text);
        sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("shomareMoshtari", txtShomareMoshtari.Text);
        sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("shoareHesab", txtShomareHesab.Text);
        sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("noeHesab", cmbNoeHesab.SelectedIndex);
        sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("sarresid", txtSarResidMah.Text);

        sc.ExecuteNonQuery();        
        sql.Close();
        select();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

and select is

```
private void select()
{
    String conString = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\\hana\\documents\\visual studio 2017\\Projects\\Bank\\Bank\\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
    SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(conString);
    String sqlString = "SELECT * FROM TblBank Order BY Id desc ";
    SqlConnection sql = new SqlConnection(conString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlString, cn);
    try {
        sql.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter sa = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlString, sql);
    using (SqlDataReader read = sa.SelectCommand.ExecuteReader())
    {
        if (read.Read())
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Load(read);
            this.tblBankDataGridViewX.DataSource = dt;
        }

    }
        sql.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: `if (read.Read())` => this should be `if (read.HasRows)`. The reader is forward-only stream, avoid using `Read()` if you have `Load()` to insert from data reader to `DataTable`.

Comment: consider using SqlDataAdapter instead of SqlDataReader

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`DataReader.Read()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.read?view=netframework-4.7.2) method will iterate result set before `DataTable.Load()`. Because the `DataReader` is a forward-only stream, it has empty result set when `DataTable.Load()` executes and `DataTable` content is still empty while setting `DataSource` for `DataGridView`. Try [`DataReader.HasRows`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.hasrows?view=netframework-4.7.2) property to check result set availability:

```
using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(conString))
{
     using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlString, cn))
     {
        try 
        {
            cn.Open();
            using (SqlDataReader read = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                // check if the reader returns result set
                if (read.HasRows)
                {
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    dt.Load(read);
                    this.tblBankDataGridViewX.DataSource = dt;
                }

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // do something
        }
     }
}
```